# OpenCV edge detection on PNG image with alpha layer

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, png

I have the following image of a logo, which is a PNG file with an alpha (transparency) channel. Very common format for logos, but here is the Reuters logo as an example:

[image]

I'm using OpenCV Canny edge detection in Python to turn this into single-colour edge template which can be used for matching with a larger image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(filepath) # Save above image and add location here
img_edged = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
```

Unfortunately, this is picking up the rectangular border around the logo, which is being masked by the alpha channel:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

I have tried the following suggestion, mentioned in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803888/opencv-how-to-load-png-images-with-4-channels), but it doesn't resolve this problem:

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

(It does make the image display correctly with imshow, but cv2.Canny still picks up the hidden "box" around the logo.)

Is there a way of preprocessing the image to avoid this problem?

Comment: An alternative solution to the one you found would be to detect edges of the transparency mask only.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate? Sounds like a useful approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, using this function discovered elsewhere on StackOverflow (have lost the link to the question - please add in comments if you find it):

```
def remove_transparency(source, background_color):
    print(source.shape)
    source_img = cv2.cvtColor(source[:,:,:3], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    source_mask = source[:,:,3]  * (1 / 255.0)

    background_mask = 1.0 - source_mask

    bg_part = (background_color * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask)
    source_part = (source_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (source_mask)

    return np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(bg_part, 255.0, source_part, 255.0, 0.0))
```

The above problem can then be solved as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = remove_transparency(img, 0)
img_edged = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
```

Giving:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For a simple logo like in the example, where all edges worth looking for are between foreground and background, the transparency mask has all the information you need:

```
 mask = source[:,:,3]
```

You can look for the edges of `mask` and find all the edges in the Reuters logo. I think this is true for most logos, but some might be more complex, though.

Comment: Just to clarify, this works if you load the image using img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), meaning the alpha channel is preserved when loading