# Opencv Python maintain null pixel

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image I am trying to run a classification on. This is the image opened in Paint 2:
[image]

And this is the image loaded into opencv when I do imshow. 
[image]

My Question is how can I maintain the null area of the image where there are no pixel values when I load the image into python and opencv. It is currently being received as white (255,255,255)?

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Volumes/EXTERNAL/ClassifierImageSets/Origional_2.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
    cv2.imshow("result",imgS)
    while (1):
        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if k==27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: For it to be transparent it needs to be the right color format, do you know what color format your png is?

Comment: @Stanley it is RGB with Alpha Channel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV : How to Load png images with 4 channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803888/opencv-how-to-load-png-images-with-4-channels)

Comment: AFAIK the imshow will not display like with a transparent layer but like black or white... but I haven't open images with alpha recently so it may have changed. However the 4 channels are there and can be processed

Answer (score 2):

Try to load the image using

```
img = cv2.imread('path_to_image',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

The [`cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) parameter should load the image as it is with default alpha value

Comment: Please, don't suggest the use of magic numbers, when the library already provides [documented named constants](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed the answer. Thanks for the feedback