# How can I combine a transparent background image in png format with jpg images using opencv_createsamples?

Tags: opencv, png, image-recognition

I'm currently working on a project that consist of detecting a hand in a given image using OpenCV commands,and due to lack of positive images, I tried to create them artificially with the command **opencv_createsamples**, the background images (or negative images ) are in `.jpg` format, and my positive one is in `.png` format with a transparent background, the expected result should be something like:
[image]

but what I got after running this command:

`opencv_createsamples -img pos2/img.png -bg bg2.txt -info info/info.lst -pnginput info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 405`
where :

1. img.png contains a hand with a transparent background
2. bg2.txt list of negative jpg images (or background )
3. info is the folder where all the samples will be created
4. info.lst is a file that contains the image path and the position(s) and number of the positive image(s) in each one

was:

[image]

as you can see, the positive image still have a white background, and there's no transparency as expected (the image is small because it's a 100x100 and the positive one is 50x50).

My question is, is there a way to get a result similar to the first image using the command **opencv_createsamples**?

Answer (score 1):

I quickly grepped through the source code of the function that is (I think) used:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/createsamples/utility.cpp

What you can see there is that everytime `imread` is called the second parameter is `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. This means whatever the source image format is it will always be converted to grayscale. If there is an alpha channel present in the image it gets [discarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803888/opencv-how-to-load-png-images-with-4-channels).

So I think given this information it is not possible to get the result you want with this function.